# Marklogic management API to schedule and delete a Task

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I am using management API to schedule a task `manage/v2/tasks?group-id=Default` and the JSON string that I send is

```
{
  "task-enabled":true,
  "task-path":"/MarkLogic/flexrep/tasks/push-local-forests.xqy",
  "task-root": "Modules/",
  "task-type": "minutely",
  "task-period" : 1,
  "task-database": "%%DATABASE%%",
  "task-modules": "%%MODULES_DATABASE%%",
  "task-user": "admin",
  "task-priority": "higher"
}
```

My question is how to set the name of the task ? as by looking at `manage-task-properties.xsd` it does not have a task name. So if I want to delete the task using management api, `DELETE /manage/v2/tasks/{id|name}` it does require task name.
So I created a random task id `task-id:9459386113689474276` into the above json and when I do this, the management api throws an exception

```
{
    "errorResponse": {
        "statusCode": "400",
        "status": "Bad Request",
        "messageCode": "MANAGE-INVALIDPAYLOAD",
        "message": "MANAGE-INVALIDPAYLOAD: (err:FOER0000) Payload has errors in structure, content-type or values. Task payload invalid."
    }
}
```

I look at the server logs, I find this

```
2017-09-12 20:11:37.721 Info: [Event:id=HTTPRequest ErrorFormat] Dispatching error code to app defined error handler:  500 manage/error-handler.xqy
2017-09-12 20:11:37.818 Info: Manage: MANAGE-INVALID (err:FOER0000): task-id
2017-09-12 20:11:37.818 Info: Manage: 169:16:/MarkLogic/manage/models/task-properties-model.xqy
```

How do I set the `task-id` or `task-name` so that I can use the management API to delete the task ? Since the Delete Management API does require the `name|id` of the task to be deleted

******* EDIT *********
I want my `FlexRep Scheduled task` to be explicitly deployed, and also only if a `flexrep` is enabled for a particular environment. I understand I can remove the deploy task command, based on some user defined variable or env, but this will remove all the deployment of other tasks as well.
  Is there a way where I can tell not to deploy a particular task ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A scheduled task unfortunately does not have a name, but it does have a task path. When you create the scheduled task, MarkLogic will create the task ID for you - you're not allowed to set one yourself.

When you need to delete the task path, you'll need to look up the ID using the Management API - you'll most likely do that via the task path (it should be very rare to have two scheduled tasks with the same task path).

Note that ml-gradle - https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle - can handle all of this for you, in case using Gradle is an option for you and/or your team.